# How to select all text content inside div using XPath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, scrapy

I want to select all text inside a `div` without considering tags inside.

```
<div>
<p>some text here <a href="">a link here  <span>span here<span></a></p>
</div>
```

I need to get the result as

> some text here a link here span here

I tried this

```
response.xpath('//div/text()')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're asking for the *string-value* of that `div`:

```
string(/div)
```

Or, if you wish whitespace to be trimmed from the ends and consolidated internally:

```
normalize-space(/div)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to `string()` it with XPath:

```
response.xpath('string(//div)').extract_first()
```

Answer (score 0):

check the following code for clarification

```
response.xpath('//div//text()')
```

and try the following for the required output

```
" ".join([i.strip() for i in tree.xpath('//div//text()') if i.strip()])
```